# Weird timestamp output in MySQL shell

Tags: mysql, timestamp

```
mysql-sql> select time_stamp, unix_timestamp(time_stamp) from historical_data 
where time_stamp > '2014-07-31' and time_stamp < '2014-10-05';
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| time_stamp          | unix_timestamp(time_stamp) |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
| 2014-07-31 19:04:00 |                 1406826240 |
| 2014-00-00 0:00:00  |                 1406913840 |
| 2014-00-00 0:00:00  |                 1407002040 |
| 2014-00-00 0:00:00  |                 1407088440 |
| 2014-00-00 0:00:00  |                 1407174840 |
```

I have a table with a TIMESTAMP column. I noticed that when I query the table from mysql shell it shows many dates as 2014-00-00 0:00:00. But when I convert to unix timestamp in my query it seems like the data is saved correctly. As if it is only the output formatting there is something wrong with...(the time stamps are also part of primary key).

This happens from august 1, 2014 until october 1, 2014, then it goes back to normal output.

Not sure if the following is relevant, but as I have no idea what causes this to happen here it is:
I have a java application that uses gson to handle json data from the web.Amongst the data is unix timestamps. These are converted to Instant objects, which is then written to the database using MyBatis.

Now, when reading back from the database everything seems to work OK, I get correct Instant objects. It is only in the mysql shell this is a problem it seems. But it is strange and uncomfortable.

Here is the problem reproduced from scratch in MySQL shell:

```
mysql-sql> select version();
+------------+
| version()  |
+------------+
| 5.7.18-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql-sql> create table test(`time_stamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into test (time_stamp) values ('2014-07-31');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into test (time_stamp) values ('2014-08-15');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into test (time_stamp) values ('2014-09-15');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
mysql-sql> insert into test (time_stamp) values ('2014-10-01');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql-sql> select * from test;
+--------------------+
| time_stamp         |
+--------------------+
| 2014-07-31 0:00:00 |
| 2014-00-00 0:00:00 |
| 2014-00-00 0:00:00 |
| 2014-10-01 0:00:00 |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql-sql> select time_stamp, unix_timestamp(time_stamp) from test;
+--------------------+----------------------------+
| time_stamp         | unix_timestamp(time_stamp) |
+--------------------+----------------------------+
| 2014-07-31 0:00:00 |                 1406757600 |
| 2014-00-00 0:00:00 |                 1408053600 |
| 2014-00-00 0:00:00 |                 1410732000 |
| 2014-10-01 0:00:00 |                 1412114400 |
+--------------------+----------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So at least I know it is not in the application layer the problem is.

Comment: Isn't it easier to copy-paste the text and nicely format it as code in the question? There is no real gain using an image in this context.

Comment: Just seemed easier to take a screen shot. But wasn't harder your way. And looks better too.

Comment: What versions of MySQL Server and MySQL Shell are you using?. I can't reproduce the problem, see [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45061671/1316440](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45061671/1316440).

Comment: @wchiquito I updated my question.

Comment: Forgot to mention, MySQL Shell 1.0.9

Comment: From **MySQL Command-Line** everything should work as expect.

Comment: Try: `mysql-sql> SELECT CONCAT(\`time_stamp\`) FROM \`test\`;`.

Comment: Yes, that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I can't reproduce the problem, there clearly seems to be a bug in MySQL Shell (see the dates in the `INSERT` and the result in the `SELECT`):

```sql
Welcome to MySQL Shell 1.0.9

Copyright (c) 2016, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type '\help', '\h' or '\?' for help, type '\quit' or '\q' to exit.

Currently in SQL mode. Use \js or \py to switch the shell to a scripting language.
mysql-sql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.18    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql-sql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `_`.`historical_data`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql-sql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_`.`historical_data` (
       ...   `time_stamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
       ... );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql-sql> INSERT INTO `_`.`historical_data`
       ...   (`time_stamp`)
       ... VALUES
       ...   ('2014-07-31 19:04:00'),
       ...   ('2014-07-31 17:04:00'),
       ...   ('2014-08-01 17:24:00'),
       ...   ('2014-08-02 17:54:00'),
       ...   ('2014-08-03 17:54:00'),
       ...   ('2014-08-04 17:54:00'); 
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql-sql> SELECT
       ...   `time_stamp`
       ... FROM
       ...   `_`.`historical_data`;
+---------------------+
| time_stamp          |
+---------------------+
| 2014-08-31 17:04:00 |
| 2014-08-31 19:04:00 |
| 2014-09-01 17:24:00 |
| 2014-09-02 17:54:00 |
| 2014-09-03 17:54:00 |
| 2014-09-04 17:54:00 |
+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql-sql> SELECT
       ...   `der`.`time_stamp`,
       ...   `der`.`ut`,
       ...   FROM_UNIXTIME(`der`.`ut`)
       ... FROM (
       ...   SELECT
       ...     `time_stamp`,
       ...     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time_stamp`) `ut`
       ...   FROM
       ...     `_`.`historical_data`
       ...   WHERE
       ...     `time_stamp` > '2014-07-31' AND
       ...     `time_stamp` < '2014-10-05'
       ... ) `der`;
+---------------------+------------+---------------------------+
| time_stamp          | ut         | FROM_UNIXTIME(`der`.`ut`) |
+---------------------+------------+---------------------------+
| 2014-08-31 17:04:00 | 1406826240 | 2014-08-31 17:04:00       |
| 2014-08-31 19:04:00 | 1406833440 | 2014-08-31 19:04:00       |
| 2014-09-01 17:24:00 | 1406913840 | 2014-09-01 17:24:00       |
| 2014-09-02 17:54:00 | 1407002040 | 2014-09-02 17:54:00       |
| 2014-09-03 17:54:00 | 1407088440 | 2014-09-03 17:54:00       |
| 2014-09-04 17:54:00 | 1407174840 | 2014-09-04 17:54:00       |
+---------------------+------------+---------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**MySQL Shell**:

```sql
mysql-sql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME('1406826240'),
       ...        FROM_UNIXTIME('1406826240', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S');
+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME('1406826240') | FROM_UNIXTIME('1406826240', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S') |
+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-08-31 17:04:00         | 2014-07-31 17:04:00                              |
+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**MySQL Command-Line**:

```sql
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME('1406826240'),
    ->        FROM_UNIXTIME('1406826240', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S');
+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME('1406826240') | FROM_UNIXTIME('1406826240', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%S') |
+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| 2014-07-31 17:04:00.000000  | 2014-07-31 17:04:00                              |
+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

A possible workaround until the bug is solved:

**MySQL Shell**:

```sql
mysql-sql> SELECT
       ...   CONCAT(`time_stamp`) `time_stamp`
       ... FROM
       ...   `_`.`historical_data`;
+---------------------+
| time_stamp          |
+---------------------+
| 2014-07-31 17:04:00 |
| 2014-07-31 19:04:00 |
| 2014-08-01 17:24:00 |
| 2014-08-02 17:54:00 |
| 2014-08-03 17:54:00 |
| 2014-08-04 17:54:00 |
+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql-sql> SELECT
       ...   `der`.`time_stamp`,
       ...   `der`.`ut`,
       ...   CONCAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`der`.`ut`))
       ... FROM (
       ...   SELECT
       ...     CONCAT(`time_stamp`) `time_stamp`,
       ...     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time_stamp`) `ut`
       ...   FROM
       ...     `_`.`historical_data`
       ...   WHERE
       ...     `time_stamp` > '2014-07-31' AND
       ...     `time_stamp` < '2014-10-05'
       ... ) `der`;
+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| time_stamp          | ut         | CONCAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`der`.`ut`)) |
+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
| 2014-07-31 17:04:00 | 1406826240 | 2014-07-31 17:04:00               |
| 2014-07-31 19:04:00 | 1406833440 | 2014-07-31 19:04:00               |
| 2014-08-01 17:24:00 | 1406913840 | 2014-08-01 17:24:00               |
| 2014-08-02 17:54:00 | 1407002040 | 2014-08-02 17:54:00               |
| 2014-08-03 17:54:00 | 1407088440 | 2014-08-03 17:54:00               |
| 2014-08-04 17:54:00 | 1407174840 | 2014-08-04 17:54:00               |
+---------------------+------------+-----------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Bug (Status: Verified) in [Bug #84704 The month in the output of a timestamp in MySQL shell is offset by 1](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84704).